# left join within referential table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table Time

[image]

Second table SectorProject

[image]

Third table Rfsector

[image]

I developed the following query

```sql
Select sum(time) as time, Sector_L1, T.id_Project
from time T
left join SectorProject SP ON t.id_Project=T.id_Project
left join Rfsector RF on RF.Sector_L2=SP.Sector_L2
GROUP BY Sector_L1, T.id_Project
```

Result and expected result

[image]

I didn't understand the result, can someone explain me why I get this result and how to modify the query in ordr to get the expected result?

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired results as text, not a link to picture. And it seems, you missed in your query GROUP BY Sector_L1, T.id_Project

Comment: Your SQL doesn't even give the results you say it does for your sample data. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef6c8aad2bf7128d47e2df78f9d739cf)

Comment: in order to sum you need to group the fields to aggregate.

Comment: id_project=[1011,201,36]
time=[48,520,120]
time_df=pd.DataFrame({'id_project':id_project,'time':time})

id_project=[1011,1011,1011,201,36]
sector_l2=['Building Materials','Financial Institution','Other Materials','Building Materials','Building Materials']

material_df=pd.DataFrame({'id_project':id_project,'sector_l2':sector_l2})

merged_df=material_df.merge(time_df, on="id_project", how="left")
print(merged_df)

grouped=merged_df.groupby(['id_project','sector_l2'])['time'].sum()

grouped.plot()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()

print(grouped)

Comment: the aggregation level is on id_project and sector_l2 but the join attribute is on id_project.  the results are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allocate time equally for a project using window functions:

```
select sum(time) as time, Sector_L1, T.id_Project,
       avg(time) over (partition by t.id_project) as imputed_time
from time T left join
     SectorProject SP 
     on t.id_Project = T.id_Project left join
     Rfsector RF
      on RF.Sector_L2 = SP.Sector_L2
group by Sector_L1, T.id_Project;
```